# Dont reset transformation when launching a new animation with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7p9uv16b/

I have few blocks rotated with different angles at start. I want to translate them along the rotated axis, on click. But the translation animation reset the rotation angle. I know that I can chain transformation to rotate + translate, but I need multiple animations for that (one per block). Do CSS provides a way to keep the current state as reference for new transformation ?

Html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="move()">
  Animate blocks
</button>
<button type="button" onclick="reset()">
  Reset
</button>
<div id="s1" class="square">
</div>
<div id="s2" class="square">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #58ACFA;
  margin: 100px;
}

.move{
   -webkit-animation: move 2s  both;
             animation: move 2s  both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
            transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
            transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#s1').css('transform','rotate(45deg)');
$('#s2').css('transform','rotate(30deg)');

function move(){
    $('.square').addClass('move');
}

function reset(){
    $('.square').removeClass('move');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS variables.

```css
.square {
  --position: 0px;
  --angle: 0deg;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(var(--position)) rotate(var(--angle));
          transform: translateX(var(--position)) rotate(var(--angle));
}

#s1 {
  --angle: 45deg;
}

#s2 {
  --angle: 30deg;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    --position: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    --position: 100px;
  }
}
```